# calculus - arc lengthof parametric curve

Tags: calculus

$ \gamma(t) = (-1+2\sin(t), 1 +2\cos(t)) \space\space\space t \in [0, 2\pi] $

The derivatives of $\gamma(t)$ are $(2\cos(t), -2\sin(t)) $.

To find its length, I must compute the following integral, but I got stuck.

$ \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{4\cos^2(t)+2\sin^2(t)}\space \mathrm{d}t
 $

Comment: Your derivatives don't seem to be correct, but if they are then you have written the integrand wrong. It should be $\sqrt{4\cos^2{(t)}+4\sin^2{(t)}}=\sqrt{4}=2$

Comment: I forgot a constant in the parametric function, I didn't realize I had written the integrand wrong, though. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to comput the length of a non-circular ellipse and so you got an [elliptic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral). Forget it. The function that you are trying to integrate has no elementary primitive. On the other hand, the length of an ellipse whose major axis has length $2a$ and whose minor axis has length $2b$ is $\pi ab$.

Comment: I see. Thank you!